# Android Gradle: error no suitable method found for replace

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-gradle-plugin

Hello i have been using the navigation drawer and of course this uses fragments, everything has been okay until i came across this error:

```
//(Radio is the name of the class i want to replace with)
Gradle: error: no suitable method found for replace(int,Radio)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument Radio cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)
```

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    if (position < 6){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();

        PlaceholderFragment.navNumber = position + 1;
        PlaceholderFragment.isOnline = isOnline();
    } else  if (position == 6){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, TvPlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();

        TvPlaceholderFragment.navNumber = position + 1;
        TvPlaceholderFragment.isOnline = isOnline();

    } else if (position == 7) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //////////// THE ERROR IS HERE /////////////
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Radio.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();

        Radio.navNumber = position + 1;
        Radio.isOnline = isOnline();

    }


}
```

Its the same as the other methods for below position 7 so i thought is must be in the Radio.class so heres the code:

```
@TargetApi(11)
public class Radio extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static int navNumber = 0;
    public static boolean isOnline = false;
public WebView webView;
/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static Radio newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    Radio Fragment = new Radio();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    Fragment.setArguments(args);

    return Fragment;
}

public Radio() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_radio_main, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.myurl));
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
            getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```

I am not new to programming just new to fragments. Can anyone help me? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you intermixing the Android framework class `android.app.Fragment` with the support library class `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Or intermixing other framework/support library classes? Check your imports.

Comment: Ive checked my import there all android.support.v4.app.Fragment